# What if a particle is observed from its own frame?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames

What if the net force on some particle is zero and we choose that particle itself as the reference frame or a frame moving uniformly relative to the particle. Can we call that frame an inertial frame of reference?

Answer (score 2):

If the net force on the particle is zero, then its momentum is constant, which in particular means that the particle is moving at a constant velocity. Thus, the rest frame of the particle (the frame moving with the particle) is inertial by definition.

The rest frame is certainly an important case, but there is nothing special about it in terms of being an inertial reference frame or not.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Any reference frame that is not accelerating is an inertial frame of reference. If the net force on the particle is zero, then it is not accelerating and therefore the reference frame of the particle is inertial. Moreover, an observer in any other inertial frame of reference will conclude that the reference frame of the particle is inertial.

Hope this helps.